# Count consecutive rows with minutes difference in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

5I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Name | Site | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Manual | BCN | 3/10/2022 11:23:13 PM |
| Manual | BCN | 3/10/2022 11:38:47 PM |
| Automatic | Madrid | 3/10/2022 11:40:32 PM |
| Manual | BCN | 3/10/2022 11:39:47 PM |
| Manual | BCN | 3/11/2022 12:44:47 AM |

It consists of a Name column, Place and Time. What I'm looking for is to count where Name and place are equal and Time is less than 20minutes between instances. In this case output would be Manual,bcn1 ->3 times as the 5th row is an hour away from the other two. The data is sorted by Time.

What I have tried is to groupby with the Name and Place and then apply a diff to Time with no avail.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
g=( df.groupby(['site','Name'])['Time'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(minutes=20))
      .groupby(df['site','Ppath']).cumsum() )
groups = df.groupby(['Site',g])['Time']
new_df = df.assign(count = groups.transform('size'))
```

This is returning the count of all values not the ones that fulfill the timedelta. The file itself is quite big with multiple Name and site places.

Many thanks

Edit1.
To clarify I'm looking at value pairs so in this case the first row with the second one. And then the second one with the third one and so on. I'm exploring a solution with a For filtering by Name and site.

Thanks

Comment: How is BCN 3? That only makes sense if your times in the first four rows are AM and not PM

Comment: It's 3 cause we count the first two and sum up the 4th as it's in between the time and the first two columsn are the same. There was a mistake where I said 4th row meaning 5th

Comment: It's not. The first two are 11 hours AFTER the 4th

Comment: Don't know if I'm not explaining correctly. What I'm looking for is the difference between times. 11:23:13 and 11:38:47 are separeted by 15minutes and 24 seconds which is inside the 20minutes treshold. The next value is 11:39:47 that is only one minute after the second one which is inside the treshold again. So we are counting 3. Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. The next value at 12:44 is really far away so it' doesn't count in this sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df = df.sort_values("Time", ignore_index=True)

output = (df.groupby(["Name", "Site"])["Time"].apply(lambda x: x.diff()
                                                                .dt
                                                                .total_seconds()
                                                                .div(60)
                                                                .fillna(0)
                                                                .le(20)
                                                                .sum()
                                                    )
          )

>>> output
Name       Site  
Automatic  Madrid    1
Manual     BCN       3
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```